# Use NULL pointer in C shared library

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dll

I am creating a C shared library. I provide a function to the user that has the declaration below:

```
int getResults(Elements** el)
```

where Elements is an array of structs provided by the user, which the function then fills with the values. The final number of calculated elements is different each time, depending on parameters in other functions, so there must be a way to inform the user about the number of them.

Instead of having a separate function to return the number of elements, the way I have implemented this is that the user can call this same function with NULL argument to get the number of existing elements:

```
int n = getResults(NULL);
```

allocate the required memory and then pass the array pointer. So, inside the function, I check:

```
if(el == NULL)
{
    return numEl;
}
else
{
    // Proceed to fill the structs.
    
    // If all good, return 0
    return 0; 
}
```

Now, my concern is, could this approach fail?

I have read that NULL does not necessarily mean a specific number, 0 that is. So, if for example a user links with the library using another compiler, standard or integrates it with C++, is it guaranteed that this equation will always be true?

Comment: *Any* approach has the potential for failure.

Comment: Philosophically speaking?

Comment: Always speaking.

Comment: It's a matter of ABI (without which you basically cannot link libraries at all). For instance, System V ABI specifies explicitly that _"A null pointer (for all types) has the value zero"_.

Comment: If the two modules/languages are compatible enough to be able to pass non-NULL pointers across the boundary, and agree on the meaning of the pointed-to memory, they should be compatible enough to agree on the definition of NULL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: For some definition of "*should*".

Comment: Relying on documentation that describes the prerequisite of calling  _the other function_ to set the value of `numEl` seems weak.  Is that a way to return a value such that user can know without a doubt that `numEI` is initialized?

Comment: `The final number of calculated elements is different each time` The way it's written, `getResults` cannot change the size of the array. The pointer `el` is passed by value, so any change the function might make to it would not be propagated back to the caller.

Comment: The library should allocate the necessary memory, and return the pointer and the length. The library should also provide a `freeResults` function that takes that same pointer and length, and frees the memory that `getResults` allocated.

Comment: @user3386109 The user may use it with C++, that's why the C++ tag. For the second comment you are right it is a double pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could this approach fail?

It could be misunderstood.

Other than that, I don't see a problem with the API.

> I have read that NULL does not necessarily mean a specific number, 0 that is. So, if for example a user links with the library using another compiler, standard or integrates it with C++, is it guaranteed that this equation will always be true?

Null is null, regardless of what number represents it. There aren't many direct guarantees in the language standards about compatibility across language / compiler barriers. This is not limited to representation of null, but many aspects of the language implementation. Generally, compilers strive to be compatible with other compilers on same system. If a compiler is compatible with another, then there is no problem. If it is not compatible, then changing API is unlikely to fix the incompatiblity.

To use a shared library is to rely on compatibility of compilers used to produce the components. If you cannot rely on the compilers being compatible with one another, then you cannot make function calls across their boundary. Instead, you would have to rely on serialised communication over for example a socket.

---

I would consider case where the compilers are otherwise compatible except for their definition of null to be highly theoretical. But there is a way to design the API such that it doesn't rely on definition of null, to avoid problem in such imaginary case: Let the user of the API supply the pointer value that the library should accept as "null".

Comment: So, in other words, "maybe."

Comment: @RobertHarvey With an implied addendum of "don't mix compilers / languages if lack of guarantees is an issue".

Comment: So, would you recommend that I abandon this approach?

Comment: Yes, but to quote your answer "There aren't many direct guarantees in the language standards about compatibility across language / compiler barriers.". If compiler 1 represents NULL with X and compiler 2 represents NULL with Y, then this will fail.

Comment: @Mr.Y So, can you rely on the compilers being compatible or not? My recommendation depends on your answer to that.

Comment: What I am saying is that I am making a shared library and have no control over what the user is going to link it with or wrap it with, be it compiler or language, and I am trying to avoid a scenario that a user send me an email one day says that even my provided examples fail to run.

Comment: @Mr.Y If you cannot control what is linked with your library, then you cannot know whether that will be compatible or not. You can avoid that by not writing a shared library. Serialised communication over a socket would be more portable.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks for your input. Please update your answer with the latest comment and I will accept it. You already did it, please ignore this.